# How to request claims in SAML2 or WS-Federation?

Tags: asp.net-identity, saml-2.0, ws-federation, kentor-authservices, sustainsys-saml2

I have ASP.NET MVC application (with OWIN) that is currently configured to use `IdP` that uses OpenID Connect  protocol. In OpenId Connect i can request claims using Scope values as a part of singin request. For example.

```
       app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44300/identity",
            Scope = "openid profile email",
            ClientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:36102/",
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
       }
```

in return `IdP` includes these claims into token, and application (SP) can access them.

Now i want to configure two more `IdP` in my application, One use `SAML2` and other user `WS-Federation`. For SAML2 Idp i am using [SustainSys](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2) library  and for WS-Federation i am using [Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation/) library.

I think `scopes` are only valid for OpenID Connect protocol, For other 2 protocols how do i request these claims that my application requires?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, scopes are only valid for OpenID Connect.

The other two protocols do not have this feature.

With ADFS e.g. as the IDP, you get the claims configured in ADFS.

Since both your SAML application and your WS-Fed application are configured as different RP, they can have different claim sets.

Comment: Understood that claim sets would be different, and my client application would transform them accordingly. But can my client application request which claims i want ( pro-grammatically). Or it has to be done as outside process by communicating with IT dept of the IdP

Comment: No - needs outside process.